# Confused by choice of polar coordinates in stokes theorem problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, stokes-theorem

> Say $F = [z^{3}, x^{3}, y^{3}]$ and circle is at $x = 2, y^{2} + z^{2} = 9$
> So I'm trying to find:
> $$\int \int curlF \cdot n dA$$

So I understand that $C$ is the boundary curve of a disk and the circle is in the $y-z$ plane. A normal vector is in the $x$ direction so the normal vector is $n = [1,0,0]$

so $$curl F = [3x^{2}, 3y^{2}, 3z^{2}]$$

$$curl F \cdot n = [3x^{2}, 3y^{2}, 3z^{2}] \cdot [1,0,0] = 3y^{2}$$

To convert to polar coordinates:

$$x = z$$
$$y = u \cos{v}$$
$$z = y \sin{v}$$

And then the integral becomes:

$$\int_0^{3} \int_0^{2\pi} 3u^{2}(cos^{2}v)ududv$$

Why is the polar coordinate transformation necessary? Why does $x = z$? Why does $y = \cos(\theta)$? I don't understand the limits of integration of the new integral... can someone explain that?

Comment: For one thing, "$x=z$" is you misreading or someone mistranscribing from written notes: the problem says at the beginning that the circle is in the plane $x=2$.

Comment: There are some other errors here, so it would help if you separated your work from that of the source you're reading. That way we could know when to say "that's a typo" versus which things are steps in your process that you could use feedback on.